# MVC jquery datatable date sorting issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, sorting, datetime, datatables

I implemented a datatable in MVC3 c#. All working fine in local development machine including sorting of DateTime column.

However, when i upload it to server and access the webpage, the datatable sorting does not sort correctly for DateTime column.

Further testing, i found out that different browsers (Chrome and IE9) yield different results.

Using DataTables debug which is available at http://debug.datatables.net/, I found out that the data type is shown to be of string type instead of date type. While i run on local development environment using vs2010, the debugging result shown to be of date type which give correct sorting.

It is strange as i uploaded the same copy of files into server and yet the result is not the same.

Any1 encounter this problem b4?

the following is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("./../Content/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("./../Content/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js")" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("./../Content/Scripts/jquery.jeditable.js")" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("./../Content/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("./../Content/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("./../Content/Scripts/jquery.DataTables.editable.js")" ></script>

        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-asc'] = function (a, b) {
                    var x = new Date(a),
                    y = new Date(b);
                    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
                };

                jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-desc'] = function (a, b) {
                    var x = new Date(a),
                    y = new Date(b);
                    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
                };

                $('#myDataTable').dataTable({ "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
//                    aaSorting defined the column to be sorted
                    "aaSorting": [[2, "desc"]]
                }).makeEditable({ sUpdateURL: "UpdateData",
                    "aoColumns":
                        [
                        numeric, 
                        string,
                        { "sType": "us_date"},
                        date,
                        string, 
                        string

                        ]
                });
            })

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input string are always in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, You should probably just use the existing `datetime_us` sorting option.  [Reference here](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting#datetime_us).

If you want more control, you could use one of the other options listed [on the same page](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting), or consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
// moment lets you specify the input format to parse
var x = moment(a, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"),
    y = moment(b, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss");

// same as before
return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried the datetime-us method and the problem still persist.

I still could not figure out why the javascript Date() does not recognize C# DateTime format in my server but it does in my local development environment.

My solution to my problem is to explicitly change the DateTime format with 
**.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")** and then everything sorting correctly.

Matt Johnson, thx for your reply though.